# Integration of WCF Webservice in classic asp

Tags: wcf, asp-classic

I have to call a soap web Service to send data from from my classic asp page to the database for which the web service is written at another end and i have to consume it so for it i had written the code but its giving error of HTML so i am putting my code and error in this query

```
<%
     cboYear = FixString(Request.Form("cboYear"))

    'For j=1 to 12
        execute("EndDay = Request.Form(""Days" & 1 & """)")
        execute("EndMonth = Request.Form(""Months" & 1 & """)")
        execute("EndYear = Request.Form(""Years" & 1 & """)")
        execute("EndTime = Request.Form(""Times" & 0 & """)")



        SendDate = trim(EndDay) & "/" & EndMonth & "/" &  EndYear
    'Response.Write "<br>START<hr>"

    Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", "https://bmwservicesuating.bmwcrinhm.in:7446/DMSI/PragmasysService.svc?wsdl",true 

    oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" 

      oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Pragmasyshh/UpdateCancellationDate"

    SOAPRequest = _
      "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_


      "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:tem=""http://tempuri.org/"">" &_


    "<soapenv:Header/>" &_

    "<soapenv:Body>" &_

       "<tem:UpdateCancellationDate>" &_



          "<tem:IP>" &_

             "<Year>" & valueyear &"</Year>" &_

           "  <Month>" & value & "</Month>" &_



         "                                           <CancellationDate>" & my value & "</CancellationDate>" &_

       "   </tem:IP>" &_

     "  </tem:UpdateCancellationDate>" &_

   " </soapenv:Body>" &_

 "</soapenv:Envelope> "&_
    "</xml>"





    oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest    
    Response.Write oXmlHTTP.responseText

    'Response.Write "<br>END<hr>" 

        'Next
%>
```

Please guide me whats wrong in it why i am getting error of 
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: URL of application
Line Number 248, Column 26: 
-------------------------^

Comment: You don't need `"</xml>"` at the end of your SOAP Envelope.

Answer (score 0):

You have assumed that the declaration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

needs an accompanying end tag which is not the case in fact placing

```xml
</xml>
```

at the end will cause a Parsing Error because it won't be able to find the starting tag

```xml
<xml>
```

Remove it to fix the Parse Error.